# How to simulate a heavy used memory

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, lru

I need to perform an experiment to demonstrate the LRU (least recent used) eviction behavior of Linux virtual memory management. In order to do so, I wrote the following code to count pages faults (using `/usr/bin/time -v`). It first allocates a continuous chunk of memory (100 pages), then touch every page periodically (every `nanosec`) for 1000 times.

```
#define npage 1000

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n = 1000;
    int nanosec = atoi(argv[2]);
    struct timespec t;
    t.tv_sec = 0;
    t.tv_nsec = nanosec;

    char* mem = malloc(npage*4*1024);
    char tmp;
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    while(count < n){
        // printf(".");
        // fflush(stdout);
        for (i = 0; i < npage*4096; i+=4096){
            tmp = mem[i];
        }
        nanosleep(&t, NULL);
        count ++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully, the larger `nanosec` is, the more page faults would occur. However, the result shows that no matter how long (up to 1s) it sleeps, the number of page faults tend to be the same.

```
sleep 100 ns
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 481
sleep 200 ns
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 479
/// ....
sleep 419430400 ns
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 483
sleep 838860800 ns
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 482
```

The only reason I would guess is that **the execution environment is not memory competitive**, i.e. 1000 pages (4MB) is fairly small and memory load from other processes is also low so OS choose not to reclaim them even the memory become inactive for a fairly long time (the longest inactive time in this case is 838860800 ns = .84 s).

So my question is two-fold,

1. Do I understand Linux eviction policy correctly? For example, how long does a page have to be inactive for the OS to evict it out.
2. Is there a standard (or commonly used) tool to simulate a memory competitive environment?

Answer (score 0):

in linux when your process grabs a new page it is mapped to the zero page. Only when you write something to it will you cause a page fault. Try writing to all the pages after you do the malloc and before you start you loop.